# rxjs returning different Observable depending on answer from first

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I have a function which accesses two Observables and returns an Observable.

At first the first Observable is subscribed. Depending on its answer a second Observable has to be subscribed (also passing a value from first Observable to it) or not. But in any case an Observable should be returned from the function. If the condition determines the second Observable has to be queried, than of course the returned Observable should only complete once the second Observable has completed. In the other case the returned Observable completes when the first Observable completes.

So far I've got this:

```
private load(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.accessControl.map((res: any) => {
        if (res.accessGranted) {
            this.dataService.getData(res.id).subscribe((v: number) => {
                this.value = v;
            }, () => {
                this.value = null;
                this.showErrorMessage();
            });
        } else {
            this.value = null;
        }
        return true;
    })
    .first();
}
```

The returned Observable is a mapped version of the first. However I've so far failed to wait for the second Observable and return a mapped version of it when the if clause evaluates to true.

**Update**

Based on answer by LLai I came up with this now:

```
private load(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.accessControl.flatMap((res: any) => {
        if (res.accessGranted) {
            return this.dataService.getData(res.id)
            .catch((err) => {
                this.value = null;
                this.showErrorMessage();
                return Observable.throw(err);
            })
            .map((v: number) => {
                this.value = v;
                return true;
            });
        } else {
            this.value = null;
            return Observable.of(null);
        }
    })
    .first();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you want the flatMap function http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html

```
private load(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.accessControl.flatMap((res: any) => {
        if (res.accessGranted) {
            return this.dataService.getData(res.id);
        } else {
            return Observable.of(null);
        }
})
```

then subscribe to this observable sequence. this will chain the api calls. here is a good resource on flatMap https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs

Comment: Thanks for leading me the right way. I tried adapting this, adding the processing of the return of the inner Observable, and an onError handling of the inner Observable, which are both important in my case. I updated it in the question, what do you think?

Comment: looks like you got it! some final thoughts. I'm not too familiar with the .first() method but I believe you do not need it here. You also may want to move the .catch() statement to after the flatmap, if you want to run that catch statement when the 1st observable fails

Comment: I've tried without the first() statement and it didn't work. Also I really want the error message to show only at the second observable. If access is denied than that's just okay. If it is granted but no data exists for the id, than that's an error. Besides that these are not the names and meanings of my real code, but it's similar.